# Shell script finds file in directory, how to pass into python script

Tags: python, unix

I have a shell script that looks through a directory and returns the most recent CVS file; I then want to pass this file into a python script.

I'm not very familiar with UNIX, am I supposed to be using arguments for the files in my shell script and how would I go about it?

This is the shell code:

```sh
file = ls -t | $path-n 2 | head -n1
```

In python:

```py
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel(file, sep='delimiter',skiprows = 3, header=None, names = colnames)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your python file is named test.py, it should look like:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel(sys.argv[1], sep='delimiter',skiprows = 3, header=None, names = colnames)
```

Then the command would be `./test.py $file` in the shell script.

sys.argv[0] is the python file name (ex test.py), and sys.argv[1] is the first argument after the file name.